# Redirect wp-login.php and wp-login.php?action=register to homepage using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

As the title suggests, how can I redirect the following URL's to the homepage of my WordPress website?

> *www.widget.com/wp-login.php
>
>   www.widget.com/wp-login.php/wp-login.php?action=register*

I have tried the following line in the .htaccess file (located at site root):

> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^action=register$
>   RewriteRule wp-login[.]php$ http://www.widget.com [R,NC,L]

Having no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/wp-login.php$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^action=register$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ http://www.widget.com   [R=301,L]
```

You can always just do a normal 301 redirect, which should include query strings too:

```
redirect 301 /wp-login.php http://www.widget.com
```

You probably want this too:

```
redirect 301 /wp-admin http://www.widget.com
```